# Invalid assignment and onload problems in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to HTML, CSS, and Javascript. So while I've been having trouble with some of the errors. Here's my code so far

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {position: absolute};
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pattern() {
            var the_body = getElementById("theBody");
            var xPos = 25;
            var yPos = 25;
            var width = 300;
            var height = 300;
            while (xPos <= 105) {
                var newDiv = docoument.createElement("div");
                newDiv.style.left = xPos;
                newDiv.style.top = yPos;
                newDiv.width = width;
                newDiv.height = height;
                var randR = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
                var randG = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
                var randB = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
                newDiv.background-color = rgb(randR, randG, randB);
                the_body.appendChild(newDiv);
                xPos += 10;
                yPos += 10;
                width -= 20;
                height -= 20;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body id="theBody" onload="pattern()">

</body>
</html>
```

This code will generate a series of squares on top of each other that get progressively smaller. It will assign each a different background color. However, I'm getting the following errors

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
newDiv.background-color = rgb(randR, randG, randB);

Uncaught ReferenceError: pattern is not defined at onload
<body id="theBody" onload="pattern()">
```

I' really appreciate some help here. I don't see what I did wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
newDiv.backgroundColor = rgb(randR, randG, randB);
```

and add after the function definition

```
window.onload = pattern;
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-color` is not a valid property name, and the value you assign to it should be a string (quoted, with variables interpolated using string concatenation). In other words:

```
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [randR, randG, randB] + ')';
```

A few other notes:

- Use `document.getElementById` instead of `getElementById`;
- You misspelled `document` in `document.createElement("div");`
- You should use `.style.width` and `.style.height` to set the dimensions of your div (and make sure the values you assign end in a unit, like `'px'`).

### Demo:

```js
function pattern() {
  var the_body = document.getElementById("theBody");
  var xPos = 25;
  var yPos = 25;
  var width = 300;
  var height = 300;
  while (xPos <= 105) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.style.left = xPos + 'px';
    newDiv.style.top = yPos + 'px';
    newDiv.style.width = width + 'px';
    newDiv.style.height = height + 'px';
    var randR = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randG = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [randR, randG, randB] + ')';
    the_body.appendChild(newDiv);
    xPos += 10;
    yPos += 10;
    width -= 20;
    height -= 20;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body id="theBody" onload="pattern()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, after adding all your suggestions, even though there's no errors anymore, it isn't showing multiple square stacked on each other as I had wanted. It's only showing that the page background changes to  a random color whenever I refresh.

Comment: Should be fixed! You forgot to add a unit to the end of each dimension (e.g. `'px'`).